# Get Part or stream of uploading file

Tags: java, hibernate

How to get part or stream of file without using request, just file in a form using hibernate .
Nb : I can't use `request.getPart();`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);`

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.